# how to get filename from an XLSX in Julia

Tags: julia, xlsx

I defined an xf as an XLSX file in julia

```
xf=XLSX.readxlsx(file)
```

Now I would like to print the file name of xf
be like

```
xf.name
```

How should I do?

I used xf.name but it doesn't work.
keep in mind xf is an excel file, not a sheet.
I know for sheet we can use sheet.name to get the name, but for a file, how can I get the name?

---

The xf should contains the information of the filename, as you can see

```
xf=XLSX.readxlsx("12as.xlsx")
print(xf)
```

It shows the filename "12as.xlsx" correctly. How can I get this info.?

---

XLSXFile("12as.xlsx") containing 30 Worksheets
sheetname size          range
Test 034 472x7         A1:G472
Test 031 472x7         A1:G472

---

solved:

```
xf.source
```

Comment: Don't you have the filename already, and isn't it `file`?

Comment: solved: xf.source

Answer (score 4):

The XLSX file that you load into Julia is an abstract representation of data that may or may not live in a file system, so the XLSX data itself does not have a concept of "file name" associated with it. However, if you read an XLSX file with `xf = XLSX.readxlsx(file)`, then a reference to the object `file` is stored as `xf.source`. So if you read the XLSX file by passing `readxlsx` a string argument `file`, the file name can be printed with the following:

```
using XLSX
xf = XLSX.readxlsx("location/of/file.xlsx")
println(xf.source)  # prints "location/of/file.xlsx"
```

However, you should know that `xf.source` [is defined as type `Union{AbstractString,IO}` in the source code](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/blob/168b971ffe1c99e30f73a151090b938463880de6/src/types.jl#L277), and this reflects the fact that `XLSX.readxlsx` can be called with an object that inherits from `IO`, like this:

```
using XLSX
open("location/of/file.xlsx") do f
    xf = XLSX.readxlsx(f) # Works just fine to open the file this way.
    println(xf.source)    # ERROR: ArgumentError: write failed, IOStream is not writeable
end
```

This code throws an exception because `xf.source` is a reference to the `IOStream` object opened with `open(file)`, and `println(io::IO)` will attempt to write a newline character to `io`, which in this case is not writable because `open(file)` defaults to read-only mode.

The concept of "file name" is something that the file system knows about, but is not something that an XLSX file necessarily knows or cares about. If you need to know the name of the file that you opened, you can use this `xf.source` hack, but it's (a) an undocumented internal feature of the package that may change, and (b) only works if you open the file by passing `XLSX.readxlsx` a string. Because you have to know the file name to use `xf.source` like this anyway, it's better to store that in some other variable and reference that when necessary:

```
using XLSX
file = "location/of/file.xlsx"
xf = XLSX.readxlsx(file)
println(file)  # prints "location/of/file.xlsx"
```